# Modification of VBA Code to retain data formatting on excel sheet before copying into Outlook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA that copies the details from an excel sheet to a outlook mail body:
Below is the macro:

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim EmailSubject As String
Dim SendTo As String
Dim EmailBody As String
Dim ccTo As String

EmailSubject = "Test"
SendTo = "superuser@superuser.com"


FirstRow = 1 
LastRow = 5
FirstCol = 1 
LastCol = 2 

For r = FirstRow To LastRow
For c = FirstCol To LastCol

For Each cell In Cells(r, c)
strtable = strtable & "  " & cell.Value
Next
Next
strtable = strtable & vbNewLine
Next

EmailBody = "Hi" & vbLf & vbLf & " body" & vbLf & vbLf & strtable & vbNewLine 

Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Itm = App.CreateItem(0)
With Itm
.Subject = EmailSubject
.To = SendTo
.CC = ccTo
.Body = EmailBody
.Display
'.Send
End With
Set App = Nothing
Set Itm = Nothing
End Sub
```

But the details on the excel sheet are in a tabular format, with some formatting. Can the table and formatting be retained, when data is copied into outlook? If Yes, how?

Comment: You could try, for instance, slecting the range, using the copy method to clipboard, and then, instead of setting the body, you use `sendkeys` to "ctrl+v" (^v). There may be a safer/better/programmatic way to paste instead of a key macro

Comment: If you want the table, why not just take the table instead of recreating it?

Comment: How to copy the table? Can you show me the places where i need to make changes in the code,and what methods to use? @Yorik

Comment: How to copy the table @Raystafarian

Comment: I don't understand your code, is it in outlook or in excel? What variables target excel?

Comment: it copies the content on excel and puts it on outlook.

Comment: `Range("Table1[#All]")`

Comment: not working @Raystafarian. 
i actually want to have a code, that can copy a table from an excel sheet, and paste it onto an outlook mail

Comment: That's how you target a table in excel, just use the right table name

Comment: its giving me "invalid use of property error". @Raystafarian
Table name is "SheetTable" and i'm using Range("SheetTable[#All]")
Where do i append the copy command in this?